# once ignored file disappears after git reset --hard

Tags: git

This problem is a bit hard to explain, let me show you step by step.

First, I have an empty folder, I add some files (a&b) and a .gitignore file which ignores file b.

```
work@Work-PC:~/gitTest$ ls -a
.  ..
work@Work-PC:~/gitTest$ echo "123" > a
work@Work-PC:~/gitTest$ echo "456" > b
work@Work-PC:~/gitTest$ echo "b" > .gitignore
```

Then, I git init, git add, and git commit.

```
work@Work-PC:~/gitTest$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/work/gitTest/.git/
work@Work-PC:~/gitTest$ git add -A
work@Work-PC:~/gitTest$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   .gitignore
#   new file:   a
#
work@Work-PC:~/gitTest$ git commit -m "c1"
[master (root-commit) 5e032d6] c1
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 create mode 100644 a
```

You can see that file b is ignored.

But now I suddenly realize that I shouldn't ignore b at first time. So I empty .gitignore and git add&commit again.

```
work@Work-PC:~/gitTest$ echo "" > .gitignore
work@Work-PC:~/gitTest$ git add -A
work@Work-PC:~/gitTest$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   .gitignore
#   new file:   b
#
work@Work-PC:~/gitTest$ git commit -m "c2"
[master 0c25718] c2
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
 create mode 100644 b
```

So far everything goes fine.

But now I want to go back to the version when I first commited, so I git reset --hard.

```
work@Work-PC:~/gitTest$ git reset --hard HEAD^
HEAD is now at 5e032d6 c1
work@Work-PC:~/gitTest$ ls
a
```

**I find that file b is missing! That's not what I want.**

**I want file b stays as original version before .gitignore is emptied, and be tracked by git only after .gitignore is emptied.**

I assume the reason file b is disappeared is that when I commit second time after emptying .gitignore, git thinks a new file b is created, so when I reset to earlier commit, git deletes that file.

How can I solve this problem? In the real case, I already have commited so many times before "emptying .gitignore", that "empty .gitignore at first place and redo everything" is not possible.

I've searched all over stackoverflow with keywords "git .gitignore reset" and got nothing. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct and desirable behavior on the part of Git. If you don't want it to delete changes, don't use `--hard`.

Just use `git reset <commit id>` and then manually pick and choose which changes to discard.